# Cannot boot into system after Bios update

Tags: linux, debian, boot

I have a Thinkpad with two hard drives running dual boot setup (Pop 22.04 LTS on drive1, Windows11 on drive2). Today I've upgraded BIOS on the laptop through firmware update on Pop: it updated succesfully, although now I cannot access Pop at all, it boots to Windows by default.

The Boot Config / Priority Order : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb3aR.jpg

After the update Windows Boot Manager was first, I moved the hard drive with Pop on it to be first (NVMe0 is Pop drive, NVMe1 is Windows drive). Also, Secure Boot and FastBoot on Windows are off.

I've tried [reparining the bootloader according to the System76 guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/), but I've run into some issues - the commands I've run in order:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme1n1p3 cryptdata
sudo mount /dev/mapper/data-root /mnt
```

> the disk is encrypted, the name according to sudo parted -ls, was /dev/nvme1n1

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in dev dev/pts proc sys run; do sudo mount -B /$i /mnt/$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
update-initramfs -c -k all
exit
sudo bootctl --path=/mnt/boot/efi install # DOESNT WORK
```

> everything worked up to the last command, it throws this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMIbE.jpg

which, honeslty, I don't understand, as `parted` seems to show that it is, in fact, esp / fat32.

Anyway, I don't know what to do, before the BIOS update the system was default booting into Pop, I could also access boot menu using F7 key during booting. Now it boots into Windows no matter what. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've solved it and I guess I'll leave a comment here if anyone has similar issue.

So I re-did the entire "System76 Repair the Bootloader" guide and it worked - the Linux Boot Manager was created, after reboot it appeared in UEFI and everything works now. The **only** thing that I could have missed in earlier tries is the `sudo vgchange -ay` in the Encrypted Disk section of the instruction (the first time I did it, I forgot to mount the esp after mounting encrypted root partition and then in further tries I just forgot about the command).

So to sum up - following [this guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/) (if you have encrypted disk): Encrypted Disk section -> `sudo mount <your esp partition> /mnt/boot/efi` -> rest of the commands in systemd-boot section (so starting at `for i in dev dev/pts proc sys run; do sudo mount -B /$i /mnt/$i; done`).